# Linux: Interaction between sched_yield and nice

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, thread-priority

In Linux, what is the interaction between `nice` and `sched_yield`? The man page for `sched_yield` suggests that the caller will yield only to processes of the same or higher priority:

> If the calling thread is the only thread in the highest priority list at that time, it will continue to run after a call to `sched_yield()`.

Yet the man page for `sched` suggests that it's not as black and white:

> The degree to which the nice value affects the relative
> scheduling of SCHED_OTHER processes likewise varies across UNIX
> systems and across Linux kernel versions.
> With the advent of the CFS scheduler in kernel 2.6.23, Linux
> adopted an algorithm that causes relative differences in nice
> values to have a much stronger effect.  In the current
> implementation, each unit of difference in the nice values of two
> processes results in a factor of 1.25 in the degree to which the
> scheduler favors the higher priority process.  This causes very
> low nice values (+19) to truly provide little CPU to a process
> whenever there is any other higher priority load on the system,
> and makes high nice values (-20) deliver most of the CPU to
> applications that require it (e.g., some audio applications).

Will `sched_yield` sometimes allow another process of lower priority to run?

*PS I'm aware that Linus Torvalds discourages using `sched_yield`; that has no bearing on my goal of understanding its behavior.*

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I don't think that's correct.  `sched_yield` is indeed a syscall, but it can only yield the current process, it can't choose who runs next.  That's determined by `sched`.

Comment: My bad, turns out after looking more into it the semantics are not that *precise*. So to clarify, what you say is that in a situation where you have two tasks, one with high priority and one with low priority, you want to know whether the call to `sched_yield` from the high priority task will ever actually return after giving a time slice away to the low priority one. Is that right?

Comment: Your excerpt from the sched man page is about the SCHED_OTHER policy, and the sched_yield man page explicitly says its behavior under SCHED_OTHER is unspecified.  In particular your quote about the highest priority list can't be assumed to be applicable to SCHED_OTHER, nor can anything else in the sched_yield man page.

Comment: @NateEldredge My simple experiment was run under default SCHED policy, and showed the same. Try it!

Comment: @SRobertJames: SCHED_OTHER *is* the default scheduling policy!

Comment: I don't doubt that you observed the behavior that you did.  It is common sense that, unless some hard realtime requirements are in play, when we have two processes and one of them has yielded, we should run the other, even if its priority is lower.  All I'm saying is that your experiment does not contradict the `sched_yield` man page, and so I wouldn't say that the man page is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Experimentation indicates that, contrary to the `sched_yield` man page, `sched_yield` will indeed yield to a process of lower priority as well.

The man page needs to be updated.

Comment: If you are testing with a process which has the default scheduling policy (`SCHED_OTHER`) then I am afraid your experiments don't prove much. As Nate said above, [the manual page](https://manned.org/sched_yield.2) for `sched_yield` specifically states: *"`sched_yield()` is intended for use with real-time scheduling policies
       (i.e., `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`).  **Use of `sched_yield()` with
       nondeterministic scheduling policies such as `SCHED_OTHER` is unspecified**
       and very likely means your application design is broken."*